# FTPS performance with small XML files but very high volume

Tags: linux, performance, file-transfer, xml, ftps

Our company is building a b2b integration with another party that requires them to deliver to us a large number **~100,000 XML files about 10-15 KB each over the course of a three hour window** everyday.  We plan to use our **FTPS server (TLS/SSL)** that is highly available and runs on Linux, for this exchange.

The other party has raised some concerns about the read/write overheads of FTPS, stating that it is likely the transfer will extend beyond the allowable window.  Our infrastructure specialists assure me that there is no issue with that number of files over FTPS specially on an HA Linux server as long we delete after file pick-up.

I want to substantiate the approach above. Has anyone implemented a high volume transfer over FTPS? Is this a bad idea and should we implement a queue based approach?

It will be too late to discover issues during our load-test.  Apologies if the question is slightly open-ended. Perhaps if you need specific details, I can provide that. *Thanks very much*

Comment: So that's an average of 10 transfers per second (peaks and valleys to be expected?)... using FTPS and that's over a WAN? What's the latency like? And are these transfers to be consecutive or is there going to be some concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**   If the servers are close together you may be able to do it, if they are far away you will likely blow your transfer window.   Either way, however, its a bad idea for the "simple" implementation.

**The fuller answer:**

I don't think this site is appropriate for the kind of question - the correct answer will be "it depends", and "you should run your own tests".   (Also maybe Serverfault would be a better forum as this forum is more for hobbiests).

That said I question FTPS as a good solution as it would seem to have a very high overhead - FTP is bad enough before adding the additional encryption overhead.

As to whether this is technically doable will significantly depend on the speed of your pipe, the distance between the servers and the number of simultaneous connections you make [ multiple connections can mitigate high latency to an extent]

If you can merge multiple files into 1 larger file, transfer them and then decompress them you will get very large substantial performance gains because:

1. You reduce the issues with latency (and encryption computational overheads, but lets ignore those as they are not substantive relative to the rest of the problem)
2. You compress the files reducing the amount of data that needs to be transferred.

You have not specified how the transfers would work - would it be a single FTPS session with multiple files being uploaded or a seperate ftps session for each file.

The latter solution - which would be easier to program I suspect - would incur a HUGE overhead as every single connection would need to be negotiated, and this negotiation is expensive relative to a small file.   (I'm not expert on FTPS, but [TLS typically adds about 6-7k overhead to each request](http://netsekure.org/2010/03/tls-overhead/) and FTPS is an FTP session wrapped in a TLS ine).

The latency per request, assuming the payload were in insignificant would go up by about 3 times.    This may not be important if the sites are on the same network, but if for example you had 1 side of the connection in New York and the other in LA 80ms you are looking at substantial latency issues when you multiply this out by the number of files, and you will probably blow your transfer window - even if the NAS can handle it.

Comment: Nice round-up. I am confident the numbers speak for themselves. 10 transactions per second is simply not do-able, you'd only have 100 msec per file. Ping time alone may well be more than that over a WAN. Unless multiple connections were utilized but even then seems iffy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer an answer here that quantifies the issue you're likely to face. I have up-voted *davidgo's* answer too because it correctly describes the issue.

Consider that 100,000 transfers over three hours equates to an average of roughly *10 transfers per second*. That's 100 milliseconds each transfer.

Server-to-server latency would have to be an order-of-magnitude lower than that, say 10 msec, for there to be any hope of keeping up with the transfer rate.

If the servers are connected via WAN, you can consider that next-to-impossible. Unless you go with multiple concurrent connections, but then if the transactions themselves are consecutive that effectively negates any potential gains concurrency offers.